# Safe connection limits for DDOS Deflate?

Tags: deflate, ddos

I work for a site that often get's attacked by bot networks. We have started to use this tool: http://deflate.medialayer.com/ which auto-bans ip's that have more open connections than the set value. By default it's set to 150, we are currently using 250.

I would like to know, how low is safe so that search bots and normal visitors do not get blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers may open up to 250 connections in total ([Firefox on Windows is limited to 48 in FF 8](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections), and by default somewhere between 4 and 16 for a single server.

In Firefox the setting is named Network.http.max-connections-per-server and defaults to 8. AFAIK Chrome has a default of 6. However, because of delays on connection timeouts the number of open connections that DDOS Deflate gets from netstat might be higher, maybe up to 30-40.

So from what I've read from various search results like [this one on Lighttpd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-set-throughput-connections-per-ip.html) is that 100 should be a safe number that won't ban regurlar users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly know, but I have added a `WARN_LIMIT` feature to the ddos.sh script so that you can set a threshold that will not get banned but you will still get warned. So you can run this script for a while with conservative limits and then apply stricter limits after you get an idea about the real-world usage.

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/ddos-deflate